# Responsive Design in SXA

Tags: sxa, mobile

I've been designing my new SXA site on my desktop computer. On a whim I decided to see what my new site design would look like on a mobile device, and I was very disappointed. The site simply shrunk down instead of rearranging itself as I had expected. Here's what my site looks like on the desktop:
[image: Desktop view of site]

Here's what the site looks like on an iPhone 5:
[image: Mobile view of site]

I was expecting the site to break at certain points and rearrange automatically in the same way that Bootstrap does. I am using the **basic** theme. I thought that SXA automatically made my site responsive.

What am I missing to make my site mobile responsive?

**Edit**

Here's the wireframe of the same page:
[image: Desktop Wireframe]

Here's what the mobile wireframes look like. I put some big arrows showing where I expected the columns to wrap, but they didn't.

[image: Mobile Wireframe]

Here's what it looks like on an actual mobile device:

[image]

Comment: How did you create the layout? Did you use the grid with rows and columns?

Comment: Yes, I used the **Splitter (Columns)** component to make the 2 columns.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the wireframe with the design on? Its hard to tell how the site has been built from the current ones. I have just tried a similar design and the columns wrapped as would have expected when reduced to a phone size.

Comment: Something that I just discovered as I was doing this was that if I resize my browser window, the wrapping seems to work just fine. However, if I use an actual mobile device (or a virtual one on BrowserStack), I don't get the wrapping. I just get really small text. I've attached another screen shot of what the mobile view looks like on a Nexus phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears your Meta Viewport may not be configured correctly, if you are seeing responsive behavior in the browser but not on a mobile device.

Try setting the *Viewport* field on */sitecore/content/[Tenant]/[Market]/Presentation/Designs* to:

```
width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no
```

... and don't forget to publish it.

**Edit:**

The path above is actually based on Zen Garden. It's changed to the Theme in SXA as pointed out by Alan. The theme is either */sitecore/media library/Themes/Theme* for default themes, or */sitecore/media library/Project/Tenant/site/Theme* for client themes.

Comment: The `Viewport` field has been moved to a different place and can be found on your **Theme** item now.

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak : as in */sitecore/media library/themes/[Theme]*? I can update answer.